# Fill null values with the closest non null value from other columns

Tags: python, python-polars

I have Polars dataframe

```
import polars as pl

data = {
    "product_id": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
    "col1": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",],
    "col2": ["b", None, "b", None, "b", None, "b", None, "b"],
    "col3": ["c", None, "c", None, None, None, None, None, None],
    "col4": [None, None, None, None, None, "d", None, None, "d"]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)


┌────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ product_id ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str        ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null │
│ 2          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null │
│ 4          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 5          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 6          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ d    │
│ 7          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 8          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 9          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ d    │
└────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I need to fill null values in column `col4` with the closest non null value from left columns (not considering `product_id` column) and create new column.

The desired output should be the following

```
data = {
    "product_id": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
    "col1": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",],
    "col2": ["b", None, "b", None, "b", None, "b", None, "b"],
    "col3": ["c", None, "c", None, None, None, None, None, None],
    "col4": [None, None, None, None, None, "d", None, None, "d"],
    "desired_column": ["c", "a", "c", "a", "b", "d", "b", "a", "d"]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)


shape: (9, 6)
┌────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────────────┐
│ product_id ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 ┆ desired_column │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---            │
│ str        ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str            │
╞════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ c              │
│ 2          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a              │
│ 3          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ c              │
│ 4          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a              │
│ 5          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ b              │
│ 6          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ d    ┆ d              │
│ 7          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ b              │
│ 8          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a              │
│ 9          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ d    ┆ d              │
└────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────────┘
```

I tried different approached but without any success. Is there any way to achieve this within Polars and not converting dataframe into dict and do all operations with Python dict and convert the result back to Polars dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "closest" means to favor the higher numbered columns ie 4,3,2,1. You can do that with just a [`coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce)

```
df.with_columns(
    desired_column=pl.coalesce(
        'col4', 'col3', 'col2', 'col1'
    )
)
shape: (9, 6)
┌────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────────────┐
│ product_id ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 ┆ desired_column │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---            │
│ str        ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str            │
╞════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ c              │
│ 2          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a              │
│ 3          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ null ┆ c              │
│ 4          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a              │
│ 5          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ b              │
│ 6          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ d    ┆ d              │
│ 7          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ b              │
│ 8          ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ a              │
│ 9          ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ d    ┆ d              │
└────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────────┘
```

You can do it more dynamically with a generator:

`pl.coalesce(x for x in df.columns[::-1] if x!='product_id')`